# Microprofile misses manifest.mf

Tags: java, manifest.mf, microprofile

I created an example microprofile app. And the readme says i can start it with java -jar myjar.jar

But when I try it i get an error that no manifest.mf exists.

I really don't have one in my example generated project. But when I extract the jar, there is one generated, but without a main class.

How is a Microprofile app even supposed to run? I know there is a class extending Application. But how should I handle this manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry just realized IntelliJ placed the projet into another folder. So now I have two folders. And handled the wrong project.